# get values from server to applet

Tags: java, applet, webserver

Good day to you all.

First of all I have to say that I have very little experience with java and web stuff but alas I cannot get around implementing this.

I have a Web Application called `ZsfCitylink` that runs on a `tomcat server` and it contains an applet called `CitylinkCharts` that can be accessed by a client using a web browser.

The problem I have is that `CitylinkCharts` needs dynamic data from the Server and I have no clue how to pass them to the applet.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you need this data only at the time the applet is loaded, or do you need dynamic data while the applet is running?

Comment: sadly I need it during runtime, i know how to pass data to the applet on startup

Comment: then you need some kind of API on your server and access it in the applet.

Comment: Have a look at [this Oracle trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html), which describes how JavaScript can call applet methods.  Of course, JS can _also_ interact with your server, e.g. via a REST call.

Comment: thank you philipp ill have a look at that post right away

Comment: @PhilippSander thank you so much this solved my problem. dont know how i missed that post when searching for similar problems but oh well thanks to you everything's fine now. have a good day.